# I have written a program in OpenGL using the GLFW and GLEW libraries in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.I am getting errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

### OpenGL program for checking extensions support

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<glew.h>
#include<glfw3.h>
#define GLEW_STATIC 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    GLFWwindow *window;
    if (!glfwInit()) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    //Exit if not initialized
    int w = 1024, h = 600;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, "glfw", NULL, NULL); //Create a window
    if (!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glewExperimental = true;        //Supports modern OpenGL
    GLenum glewError = glewInit(); //Initialize GLEW
    if (glewError != GLEW_OK){
        cout << "GLEW Error: " << glewGetErrorString(glewError)<<endl;
    }
    if (!GLEW_VERSION_2_1){
        cout << "Glew not supported" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    const GLubyte *p = glGetString(GL_VERSION);  //Check GL version
    cout << "Graphics Driver: " << p << endl;
    const GLubyte *q = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
    cout << "SHader Version: " << q << endl;
    if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_array_object){
        cout << "genVertexArrays supported" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

>

```
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\K_FPS.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\D3DX9_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\d3dx10_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\d3dx11_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\D3DX8Wrapper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\D3DCompiler_43.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17227_none_dad9452e5bcb7986\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\Razer Cortex\EasyHook32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dsound.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:[C:\Users\ak1132\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\Debug\OpenGL.exe]CheckHookPath start
C:\Users\ak1132\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\Debug\OpenGL.exe\dota 2 beta\dota.exeH:\Games\Naruto Shippuden Ultimate Ninja Storm RevolutionH:\Games\Borderlands The Pre-Sequel\Binaries\Win32H:\Games\Middle Earth Shadow of Mordor\x64CheckHookPath end
CheckHookFullPath start
CheckFullPathHookMatch start
CheckFullPathHookMatch end
CheckHookFullPath end
**This app is not contained in hook (full)path, So we don't handle it**
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig4icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'OpenGL.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:[C:\Users\ak1132\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\OpenGL\Debug\OpenGL.exe]The program '[5964] OpenGL.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: I don't see a description of the problem. "Doesn't work" is NOT sufficient. I also do not see any errors that would indicate any particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one reason why you are getting this errors. Maybe you are trying to run your project on mac in parallels, and parallels doesn't support switching between discrete and integrated video cards very well(or, maybe, you forbid to use discrete card in settings). So, visual studio is trying to execute this code on integrated video card, but openGL needs the discrete one.